# Capturing screen as a video stream

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, video-capture

I want to capture live video of my Windows 7 computer, and later on have it streamed lived to a client to view as a livestream. Somewhere I heard that I could use C to make a virtual device and have the computer render the screen on that, and just output it through a socket. But, I've searched and I can't find any way to do this.

So what I'm looking for is maybe a tutorial or place to start with capturing live screen output and have it transmitted through the internet to a client that can view it live.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)